# Microsoft Graph API: No web-hooks for some emails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-webhooks

We use Microsoft Graph to [subscribe to webhooks](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks) from emails. Additionally, as a backup procedure we also [crawl the messages directly](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages).

We crawl around 5 million emails a day, and we see that each day consistently around 1%-2% of these emails are not sent to us via the webhook, although the subscription for this principal is active (and other email notifications from this user are indeed sent).

Is there any logic on the Microsoft Graph side to not send webhooks for certain types of emails by design? or is it just a problem on the notification mechanism?

(Obviously crawling them, as we do now, is a viable backup option, but that also means the processing of the email will be delayed)

Answer (score 0):

I currently have a similar webhook setup and we get around 200-300 emails and I notice that the subscription service usually misses out on 1-2 per day since sometimes some emails come around at the same time. I have also noticed that the data structure is an array of objects when we get two or more emails at the same time. What we have put into place is basically a cron scheduled script that checks the mailbox on specific time intervals, such as every 5 minutes, every 10 minutes and so on. This is the only solution that has worked for my application to capture every single email.